# Trouble saving selected images from phpickerviewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Here's my code

```
func picker(_ picker: PHPickerViewController, didFinishPicking results: [PHPickerResult]) {
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    let imgName : String = UUID.init().uuidString
    
    guard let itemProvider = results.first?.itemProvider else { return }
    if itemProvider.canLoadObject(ofClass: UIImage.self) {
        for result in results {
            result.itemProvider.loadObject(ofClass: UIImage.self, completionHandler: { (image, error) in
                
                if let newImage = image as? UIImage {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async { [self] in
                        let newImgInfo = MediaHandler.saveImg(albumName: albumName, imgUrl: imgName)
                        self.imageArray.append(newImage)
                        print(self.imageArray.count)
                        self.imageDataArray.append(newImgInfo)
                        DataHandler.saveImgData(imageName: imgName, image: newImage)
                        self.collectionView.reloadData()
                       }
                   }
                else {
                    print("wrong")
                }
            })
        }
    }
    self.collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

If I select one image at a time add add to the collection view it works fine, I can leave the view and come back and all is well,
[image]
but if I select more than one image, when I leave the view and come back it just shows multiple copies of the same image.

[image]

Any clues as to why would be appreciated. I might ad that if I use a UIImagePicker everything works fine. I'm just wanting to allow multiple selection with the image picker.

Answer (score 0):

looks to me like you are not giving new imgName inside your loop. Need to generate unique asset IDs. I'm just trying to get to step one here and get an image back.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).